# why onClick event not working even after removing the disable attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, react-functional-component

Please ignore the 'if' condition, below is just an example. my requirement is to work with useRef for enabling and disabling a button based on certain condition. In below code onClick functionality not working even when i enabling the button on certain condition

```
function App() {
  const buttonRef = useRef(null);

  const name = 'Pilla'
  if(name === 'Pilla'){
    buttonRef.current.setAttribute('disabled', false)
  }else{
    
    buttonRef.current.setAttribute('disabled', true)
  }
const handleButtonClick = () => {
    console.log('Button clicked!');
  };

return (
 <button ref={buttonRef} onClick={handleButtonClick}>
        Click Me
 </button>
)}
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console? Like `TypeError: can't access property "setAttribute", buttonRef.current is null`, for example. It's not clear why you're using a ref - you could just add `disabled={name === 'Pilla'}` to your button instead.

Comment: can you verify is the disabled attribute is gone ? use inspect html

Answer (score 0):

You are using **wrong way to disable button in react**. Here is right way to use.

```js
function App() {
  const name = 'Pilla';

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    console.log('Button clicked!');
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={handleButtonClick} disabled={name === 'Pilla'}>
      Click Me
    </button>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Just fixing your code.

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function App() {
  const buttonRef = useRef(null);
  console.log("in app")
  const name = 'Pilla'

  useEffect(() => {
    if (name === 'Pilla') {
      console.log(name)
      buttonRef.current.disabled = false; // Right way
    } else {
      buttonRef.current.disabled = true;
    }
  }, [])'Pilla';

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    console.log('Button clicked!');
  };

  return (
    <button ref=onClick={buttonRefhandleButtonClick} onClick=disabled={handleButtonClickname === 'Pilla'}>
      Click Me
    </button>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: See my comment. You don't need `ref` and you certainly don't need an effect. `disabled={name === 'Pilla'}` is really all you need.

Comment: I just created a simple condition in this code but actual condition is different in my code. So I have a form fields, when these fields are filled with answers then only I should be able to enable the button. I want to do this with useRef. so haw can it be done

Comment: @AdityaVarma I have edited the answer. you can use below code.

Answer (score 0):

As Andy mentioned in their comment you don't need a `ref` to disable the element. You can set the `disabled` attribute directly on the button like demonstrated below.

```
function App() {
  const name = 'Pilla'
  
  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    console.log('Button clicked!');
  };

  return (
   <button disabled={name !== 'Pilla'} onClick={handleButtonClick}>
        Click Me
   </button>
  )
}
```

Comment: I just created a simple condition in this code but actual condition is different in my code. So I have a form fields, when these fields are filled with answers then only I should be able to enable the button. I want to do this with useRef. so haw can it be done